# Dev Express XtraGrid Checkbox

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a problem with a checkedit in DevExpress XtraGrid control.

I've created unbound column in code (not via wizard), and that checkbox can not be checked by mouse.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub DataViewFrm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim data As New DataTable
    data=getDataTable("select....")

    gridViewer.DataSource = data

    Dim Tick As New RepositoryItemCheckEdit()

    gridViewer.Refresh()

    Dim unbColumn As GridColumn = gridvwViewer.Columns.AddField("Coba")
    unbColumn.VisibleIndex = gridvwViewer.Columns.Count
    unbColumn.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Boolean
    unbColumn.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = True
    unbColumn.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = False

    gridvwViewer.Columns(8).ColumnEdit = Tick     
End Sub
```

Here is the result: [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide data for unbound columns by handling the [ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) event.
Here is the demonstration of the `ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData` event usage for read/write scenario (C#):

```
//...
var unbColumn = gridView1.Columns.AddField("Coba");
unbColumn.VisibleIndex = gridView1.Columns.Count;
unbColumn.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Boolean;
CobaValues = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
gridView1.CustomUnboundColumnData += gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData;

//...
IDictionary<int, bool> CobaValues;
void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Column.FieldName == "Coba") {
        if(e.IsGetData) {
            bool value;
            if(CobaValues.TryGetValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, out value))
                e.Value = value;
        }
        if(e.IsSetData) {
            CobaValues[e.ListSourceRowIndex] = (bool)e.Value;
        }
    }
}
```